# convert non latin characters

Tags: php, utf-8, encode

How to convert string with non latin charaters like this:

```
伊藤りな
```

To this:

```
%E4%BC%8A%E8%97%A4%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AA
```

In php. THanks ;)

Comment: http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: Omg lol, im soo stupid :D Make it as an answer, I'll accept it ;)

Comment: no problem :) This is such a basic thing though, it's hardly likely to benefit future generations. You can delete the question if you want (using the "delete" link).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) php function:

```
urlencode($string)
```